# BNF repeating sequence of characters

Tags: expression, bnf, repeat

How do I find a sequence of 3 or more "a" followed by the same number of "b" with a BNF expression?

I know that

```
{<letter>} or {<letter> | <digit>}
```

are used for repetitive items occuring zero or more times but I don't know how to get the number of times "a" has repeated to make sure "b" repeats the same number of times

Comment: BNF is not a description of regular expressions but context-free grammars. Just as a side-note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<valid-string> ::= "aaa" <ab> "bbb"
<ab>           ::= "a" <ab> "b" | ""
```

This starts off with three `a` and three `b` to take care of the minimum requirement. Then it allows the insertion of `a` and `b` at the same time (keeping the amount the same) while repeating itself in the middle of the string.

Comment: Thank you, this changed the way I was thinking about the problem. I had it stuck in my head that I would have to somehow count the number of times "a" occured and use that to make sure "b" followed.

Comment: @user1807108 that's the way you would design the corresponding push-down automaton. context-free grammars usually just work by mirrored insertions.